# Recovering unsaved data after windows blue screen

Tags: data-recovery, window

I had recently a windows blue screen. I had an unsaved mathematica notebook which I cannot find anymore. I saw online some tools that offer to recover such files but need subcription. Is there anything I can do to recover them without paying?

Comment: Turn the computer off. DO THAT RIGHT NOW, if you haven't already. Running the computer now increases the chance you will not be able to recover data. Pull the drive. Connect it to a different computer as a secondary storage device, then carefully read this question and the answers to it: https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Comment: @music2myear the link is more related to memory disks right? My case is somewhat specific to Windows no? Maybe there is a specific methodology to it

Comment: No, the answers there cover multiple situations, including hard disks. It says right there at the top that it applies to all types of storage devices, including hard drives.

Comment: To rule out the dump file as a source of the data, is there a chance the computer was set to create a complete or active dump and if so, you have the file C:\windows\memory.dmp that matches the time it crashed?

Comment: If the data was in memory at the time of the crash, it is gone forever.